# React/Redux/ImmutableJS get() returns undefined

Tags: react-redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to update my redux store, after an api call, by merging the payload with an initial state of Map(). I can access the state properties using dot notation, within mapStateToProps, but when trying to call state.get('prop') the value is undefined.

***actions.js***

```
export function loadPackages() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return PackageApi.getAllPackages().then(packages => {
      dispatch(loadPackagesSuccess(packages));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}

export function loadPackagesSuccess(packages) {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_PACKAGES_SUCCESS',
    packages
  }
}
```

***reducer.js***

```
const reducer = (state = Map(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_PACKAGES_SUCCESS':
      return update(state, {$merge: action.packages});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

***Packages.jsx***

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state.results); // (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  return {
    state,
    packages: state.get('results') // undefined
  };
}
```

***Edit***

***reducer.js***

```
const initialState = Map({
  packages: {
    totalCount: null,
    results: List(),
    dir: null,
    totalPages: null,
    limit: null,
    sort: null,
    page: null
  }
});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_PACKAGES_SUCCESS':
      return state.set('packages', fromJS(action.packages));
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

***Packages.jsx***

```
export class Packages extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadPackages(this.props.state));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        {this.props.results ?
        <PackageList allPackages={this.props.results} /> :
        <h3>No Packages Available</h3>}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state.getIn(['packages','results'])); 
  /* Doesn't print the actual value of results but shows the 
     immutable structure: List {size: 10, _origin: 0, _capacity: 10, 
     _level: 5, _root: null, …} */
  return {
    packages: state.get('packages'),
    results: state.getIn(['packages','results'])
  };
}
```

***PackageList.jsx***

```
const PackageList = ({allPackages}) => {
  const packageItems = allPackages.map(pkg =>
    <li key={pkg.get('id')}>{pkg.get('packageName')}</li>
  );
  return (
    <ul className="packages">
      {packageItems}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If structure in state is wrong, you have issue in reducer.

Replace this: `return update(state, {$merge: action.packages});`

With this: `return state.set('packages', Immutable.fromJs(action.packages));`

Now you use vanilla js immutable data mutation helper from  https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html which returns new base JS objects/arrays etc. and is not related to Immutable.Js library and you try to use Immutable.js methods on bare JS object.

Comment: I see. I updated with your suggested change and I'm able to get values from state with get() and getIn(). When I iterate over the results the only way I'm able to render properties of the payload is by calling item.get('prop'). Is this the correct way to iterate over an immutable structure? Also, logging state.getIn(['packages','results']) to the console doesn't print the property value, It just shows the immutable description of the value.

Comment: @neridaj if "results" is another immutable structure, so it will print it. You can transfer back to js with `.toJS()`. To get value from immutable js structure you have to use `.get` or `.getIn`, yes.